# gorouter refresh page on pop or go or push

Tags: flutter, gorouter

How can I do this with GoRouter??

```
         `await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const HomeMainContentsPage()))
              .then((value) {
            setState(() {});
          });`
```

This code will navigate to HomePage and refresh it.
Trying to do the same with Gorouter.

I tried this

```
ref.read(goRouterProvider).go('/');
```

and there is no way to listen to the Future here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define the home page in `GoRouter`like this:

```dart
GoRouter(
  ...,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: 'home-page',
      builder: (context, state) => HomeMainContentsPage()
    ),
    ...
  ]
)
```

Then, you need to add router config to `MaterialApp` like this:

```dart
final router = <router initialization code>
MaterialApp.router(
  ...
  routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
  routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
  routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
)
```

Then, you can simply use `context.go('/')` or `context.goNamed('home-page')` to navigate to the `HomeMainContentsPage`. No need to use Provider's ref here, as it is easier to access the router from a context.